# Android recyclerView adapter show only first item

Tags: android

in this my `RecylcerView` adapter i putting some data, but my adapter show only the first item if data, for more information :

My Activity `onCreate` method:

```
List<EwalletModel> data = new ArrayList<>();

data.add(new EwalletModel("dd", "", "", ""));
data.add(new EwalletModel("ww", "", "", ""));
data.add(new EwalletModel("ee", "", "", ""));
data.add(new EwalletModel("rr", "", "", ""));

ewalletRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ewalletsList);

ewalletRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adapter = new GetEwalletsAdapter(this, data);
ewalletRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_toolbar"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/new_ewallet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button_actions"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/create_new_ewallet"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ewalletsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my `GetEwalletsAdapter` class:

```
public class GetEwalletsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomGetEwalletViewHolder> {

    IOnItemClickListener iOnItemClickListener;
    List<EwalletModel> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public GetEwalletsAdapter(Context context,List<EwalletModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomGetEwalletViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View                       v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ewallet_items, parent, false);
        CustomGetEwalletViewHolder holder = new CustomGetEwalletViewHolder(v, context);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomGetEwalletViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.e_account_number.setText(list.get(position).getAccount_number());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void setData(List<EwalletModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

`getItemCount` and `list` size is 4 in debug mode, but i don't know why my list has one item into `RecyclerView`

Comment: Your View item is full screen?

Comment: Do you call setData anywhere in your code?

Comment: add your code of custom view of each item (adapter layout) maybe its height is match parent

Comment: @mehdiakbarian Thanks baradar :)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. The bug is in the layout file.  What is happening is that when the first item is created it is filling up the entire screen. To fix this change the layout height of your layout manager. Change it from

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

to

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score -1):

I got the same bug when I changed the buildToolsVersion and com.android.support:recyclerview version from 23 to 24.

Comment: Please share a solution to the problem.